# Cakephp user authentication in a web service

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

cakephp 2.1. I am developing a cakephp application , also web service for third party application to access data. Output is json.

First time when user logs in through web service we create some authentication token and for every next call client will send the authentication token and I have to check authentication token available to allow other actions of app.

I wrote a login function. when user tries to logs in , it returns success or failure message. This is where I stuck. How to create this authentication token? Where does cakephp store user related session? Can I write session like

> $this->Session->Write('check.session','random string')

and then read it in second call using

$this->Session->read('check.session').

Or is there any other better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats fine, ( lower case write! ) if you were using the Auth Component you could store it in there too.

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.User.auth_token',$auth_token);

#stored in the session at

['Auth']['User']['auth_token']
```

You may want to install [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) , a great tool for debugging including browsing the session.

Comment: Thanks for that. I got an Idea now. Yes, I am using Auth component. Can you please tell me how to store it Auth component? Also I am wondering What is that I should return to client ( mobile app here ) upon successful login so that they send it with every other request to access protected actions?

Comment: Well storing the token is done as I've shown, so accessing it done using Session->read() . Im not sure what you final question is, can't you just access the token in each action by reading the session?